# Problem with style file in wordpress not working

Tags: php, css, wordpress

so i'm trying to upload a css file and a javascript file to a custom theme on word press , nothing show up on the webpage when i open it and there are no elements at all , but when i delete the functions.php file the webpage appears but with no style of course i don't know what's the problem

here is my functions.php file

```
<?php

function industrialabc_files(){
    wp_enqueue_script('main-script', get_theme_file_uri('/main.js'),
    NULL, '1.0',true);
wp_enqueue_style('industrialabc', get_stylesheet_uri());
};
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'indutrialabc_files');
```

Comment: I guess you are using this functions.php in your child-theme, right? What happens if you leave the file only with `<?php` at the begining and nothing more?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try like that, and let me know:

```
<?php
function industrialabc_files(){
    wp_enqueue_script('main-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/JS_FILE_NAME.JS',NULL, '1.0',true);
    wp_enqueue_style('industrialabc', get_template_directory_uri() . '/YOUR-STYLE_FILE_NAME.css');
};
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'indutrialabc_files');
?>
```

Comment: Still nothing happens

Comment: have you added <?php wp_head(); ?> in your header.php file before closing the </head> tag?

Comment: yes i did that already

Comment: Okay, that's strange, do you mind to share the URL so that I can check (if it's not at localhost.)

Comment: yes of course i deleted the functions.php and everything show up normally  : industrialabc.us

Comment: It's showing me complete blank page, can you please add the functions.php again so that I can check the error in console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243044/discussion-between-rakesh-sharma-and-bakaacode).

Comment: here is what shows up when i delete the functions.php , let me know when u want me to add it to see what happens